# .replace javascript not working

Tags: javascript, replace

Hi i am working in java script i have a string

```
var data = 'http://baab.bh/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/e/test.jpg';
```

i want to replace **/image/** into **'image/440x600'** i am using this function

> .replace()

but its not working here is my code

```
var data ='http://baab.bh/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/e/test.jpg';
    data.replace('/image/', '/image/440x600/');
    console.log(data);
```

its showing same not replacing **/image/** into **'image/440x600'**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable. They cannot be modified.

The `replace` method **returns** the modified string, it doesn't modify the original in place.

You need to capture its return value.

```js
var data = 'http://baab.bh/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/e/test.jpg';
data = data.replace('/image/', '/image/440x600/');
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 4):

Strings in JavaScript are immutable. Thus the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function doesn't change the string but returns a new one, you have to use the returned value:

```
var data = data.replace('/image/', '/image/440x600/');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      //Your Actual Data
      var data ='http://baab.bh/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/e/test.jpg';

        // Changing the reference of the Actual Data and gets a new String
    var ChangedData =data.replace('/image/', '/image/440x600/');

   // To Verify the Output
        console.log(data);

        console.log(ChangedData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check this

```
    var str = "http://baab.bh/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/e/test.jpg";

var res = str.replace("image", "image/440x600");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -2):

Using global regular expression

```
var data = data.replace(/image/g, '/image/440x600/');
```

Comment: Why? The substring only occurs once in the string in the question.

Comment: @Quentin would you like to explain what will be overhead of using this? Its just another way of doing it.

Comment: What does overhead have to do with it? The OP had a problem. Using a regular expression instead of a string won't solve that problem. Telling them to use a regular expression instead of a string is misleading and doesn't help them.

Comment: @Quentin :) i like the term misleading.